# debug and fix code for scoring dancers

Tags: python

this is background: the code is for a dancing competition with 6 couples and 5 judges. to gt scores the judges input scores and the highest and lowest are removed and the rest are added to create a total score.

my code prints the error message at   line 31 saying type error is not suscriptible and assuming it will say this for all other lists please help me debug my code producing a working solution to have a user input a score 5 times for 6 couples then removing the highest and lowest and displaying all in a list on a text file.

when using the () advice given below this error message occurs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samuel/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/text saving scores.py", line 32, in 
    listA = list(coupleA_judge1, coupleA_judge2, coupleA_judge3, coupleA_judge4, coupleA_judge5)
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (5 given)
how do i fix this

```
coupleA_judge1 = int(input("score couple A out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleA_judge2 = int(input("score couple A out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleA_judge3 = int(input("score couple A out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleA_judge4 = int(input("score couple A out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleA_judge5 = int(input("score couple A out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))

coupleB_judge1 = int(input("score couple B out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleB_judge2 = int(input("score couple B out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleB_judge3 = int(input("score couple B out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleB_judge4 = int(input("score couple B out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleB_judge5 = int(input("score couple B out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))

coupleC_judge1 = int(input("score couple C out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleC_judge2 = int(input("score couple C out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleC_judge3 = int(input("score couple C out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleC_judge4 = int(input("score couple C out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleC_judge5 = int(input("score couple C out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))

coupleD_judge1 = int(input("score couple D out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleD_judge2 = int(input("score couple D out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleD_judge3 = int(input("score couple D out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleD_judge4 = int(input("score couple D out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleD_judge5 = int(input("score couple D out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))

coupleE_judge1 = int(input("score couple E out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleE_judge2 = int(input("score couple E out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleE_judge3 = int(input("score couple E out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleE_judge4 = int(input("score couple E out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))
coupleE_judge5 = int(input("score couple E out of 10 (max 10, min 1)"))

listA = list(coupleA_judge1, coupleA_judge2, coupleA_judge3, coupleA_judge4, coupleA_judge5)
coupleA_lowest = min(listA)
coupleA_highest = max(listA)
scoresA = list.remove("coupleA_lowest", "coupleA_highest")
print(scoresA)

listB = list(coupleB_judge1, coupleB_judge2, coupleB_judge3, coupleB_judge4, coupleB_judge5)
coupleB_lowest = min(listB)
coupleB_highest = max(listA)
scoresB = list.remove("coupleB_lowest", "coupleB_highest")
print(scoresB)

listC = list(coupleC_judge1, coupleC_judge2, coupleC_judge3, coupleC_judge4, coupleC_judge5)
coupleC_lowest = min(listA)
coupleC_highest = max(listA)
scoresC = list.remove("coupleC_lowest", "coupleC_highest")
print(scoresA)

listD = list(coupleD_judge1, coupleD_judge2, coupleD_judge3, coupleD_judge4, coupleD_judge5)
coupleA_lowest = min(listD)
coupleA_highest = max(listD)
scoresA = list.remove("coupleD_lowest", "coupleD_highest")
print(scoresD)

listE = list(coupleE_judge1, coupleE_judge2, coupleE_judge3, coupleE_judge4, coupleE_judge5)
coupleE_lowest = min(listE)
coupleE_highest = max(listE)
scoresE = list.remove("coupleE_lowest", "coupleE_highest")
print(scoresE)


coupleA_lowest = min(listA)
coupleA_highest = max(listA)
list.remove("coupleA_lowest, coupleA_highest")

coupleA_total_score = 0
coupleB_total_score = 0
coupleC_total_score = 0
coupleD_total_score = 0
coupleE_total_score = 0

judges = ["judge 1", "judge 2", "judge 3", "judge 5", "total"]

couples = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

data =([coupleA_judge1, coupleA_judge2, coupleA_judge3, coupleA_judge4, coupleA_judge5, coupleA_total_score]
       [coupleB_judge1, coupleB_judge2, coupleB_judge3, coupleB_judge4, coupleB_judge5, coupleB_total_score]
       [coupleC_judge1, coupleC_judge2, coupleC_judge3, coupleC_judge4, coupleC_judge5, coupleC_total_score]
       [coupleD_judge1, coupleD_judge2, coupleD_judge3, coupleD_judge4, coupleD_judge5, coupleD_total_score]
       [coupleE_judge1, coupleE_judge2, coupleE_judge3, coupleE_judge4, coupleE_judge5, coupleE_total_score])
row_format ="{:>10}" * (len(judges)+1)
print (row_format.format("", *judges))
for score, row in zip(couples, data):
    f.write(row_format.format(score*row))
```

Answer (score -1):

You definitely need to use some loops so there not so much code, but I think the issue is that on line 31, you are calling the list method as list[] when you should use list(). I'm not at my computer so this could not be it but it looks off to me

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking the list() idea presented by Dan might be a good start. One other option you have here is to sort the list and then draw the substring of the list (substring containing values less than the highest and greater than the lowest) instead of removing the max and min, though it would be more memory efficient to remove the max and min I suppose.